# The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous one

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to upgrade my previous version app into the Android market,but it shows an error as "The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous one". I am also having previous version apk file.but dont know how to solve this certificate issue..Can someone pls guide me the steps on how to upgrade this new version app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely read this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

When you published the app the first time you must have used a certificate - it's mandatory. To upgrade the app you must use the same certificate to sign the upgraded app.

If you lost the certificate, there is no way to perform upgrade. You will need to remove app from market and add a new one. This will not upgrade the app for existing users.

Comment: but how can I extract the previous certificate signed from the previous apk file? I am having previous version apk file

Comment: You cant do that - the apk does not contain the certificate. If it did then other people could extract it and update your app, right?

Comment: Then whats the procedure to upgrade this app?

Comment: @Kanika, You signed your application with a private key. Your apk file only has a public key now. It's impossible to get the private key back from your apk, unless you're the NSA or something. The real question is. What happened to your initial certificate, it should still be on the original computer you developed the app with. Did you switch computers? Did you wipe your drive? If the answer is "no" to both those questions (hopefully it's "No"). What kind of computer do you have? a PC? or a Mac? Also, if a PC what version of Windows/linux are you using?

Comment: yes I switch the computer,and I am using Windows XP.The other person upload the previous version of the app into the Android market,and he has given me the apk file but now i had upgrade it and want to upload my new version into the Android market. but I am not getting how to solve this certificate issue?

Comment: For the last time - NOW PLEASE LISTEM:

Comment: I'll put it simply: IF YOU LOST THE CERTIFICATE YOU CAN NOT UPGRADE THE APP. Period. No way around it. Please stop asking. You will only get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading any application certificate **must** be same as before or you can do by installing whole application and again **reinstall**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same keytool that you used for previus app...